# An implication of strong-operator continuity.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

The question is to show that if $f$ is a SO-continuous functional on $\mathcal{B}(H)$ [bounded linear operators on Hilbert space $H$]. Then I have to show that it's WO-continuous as well. The hint states that (assuming SO-continuity of $f$) there exists $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ such that, for all $T$ we have $$|f(T)|\le\sum_{i=1}^n||Tx_i||$$. I am having trouble seeing how this is true, can someone please elaborate? I think comparing with the neighbourhood basis which is of form $\cap_{i=1}^n\{T'\in\mathcal{B}(H):||T(x_i)-T'(x_i)||<\epsilon\}$, but am kinda stuck in implementing my idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you quote which texts are you following?

Comment: It was posed by a friend, will ask him. I found a proof in Conway's "Course in operator theory" and its similar.

Comment: Well if $T =0$ then it is trivial. If $T\neq 0$ when $\|Tx\|=1$ for some $x$. Then chose $n$ big enough and $x_1 = \cdots x_n = x$ will give the inequality. But that sounds stupid.

Comment: @ArcticChar The statement should be read as "There exist $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that for all $T$ ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All topological notions in the following refer to the strong operator topology. Since $f$ is continuous, the set $\{T\in B(H): |f(T)|\leq 1\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$. Since the sets of the $\bigcap_{j=1}^n\{T\in B(H) : \|Ty_j\|<\epsilon\}$ form a neighborrbood basis at $0$, there are $y_1,\dots,y_n\in H$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$
\{T\in B(H): |f(T)|\leq 1\}\subset \bigcap_{j=1}^n\{T\in B(H):\|T y_j\|<\epsilon\}.
$$
Rescaling yields
$$
|f(T)|\leq \frac 1 \epsilon\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\|Ty_j\|\leq \frac 1 \epsilon \sum_{j=1}^n\|T y_j\|.
$$
Thus the vectors $x_j=y_j/\epsilon$, $1\leq j\leq n$, have the desired property.